# Select month from input field and then display total days in another input field

Tags: javascript

I select a month from a input field and also select class from dropdown. After select those click on a button then display total days in another input field with other data in a table from database.
All code are work well and display data from database. But when I use a javascript for display total day after then the data didn't display in table.
I couldn't find out the error. here is the javascript code:

```php
function calculateTotalDays(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var monthInput = document.getElementById("input2");

  var number = 0;
  while (true) {
    var totalDaysInput = document.getElementById("totalDaysX" + number);
    if (totalDaysInput == null) {
      break;
    }

    var selectedDate = new Date(monthInput.value + "-01");
    var year = selectedDate.getFullYear();
    var month = selectedDate.getMonth() + 1;

    var totalDays = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
    totalDaysInput.value = totalDays;

    number++;
  }
}
```

Where is the wrong with this code? Now I update the question. Add the 2nd part of code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid page-body-wrapper">
    <div class="main-panel">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h3>Attendance of <?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?></h3>
                <br>
                <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Select Month</strong>
                    <input id="input2" type="month" name="whichmonth" required="true" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h1>Select Class</h1>
                    <select name="whichbatch" class="form-control" id="input1">
                      <option value="One">One</option>
                      <option value="Two">Two</option>
                      <option value="Three">Three</option>
                      <option value="Four">Four</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger col-md-2 col-md-offset-5" style="border-radius:0%" value="Search" name="batch" onclick="calculateTotalDays(event)" />
                  <table class="table table-stripped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Id. No.</th>
                        <th scope="col">Student Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Father's Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Class</th>
                        <th scope="col">Present</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Status</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <?php
                        if (isset($_POST['batch'])) {
                          $i = 0;
                          $number = 0;
                          $batch = $_POST['whichbatch'];
                          $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "madrasadb");
                          $all_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id,name,fname,class from smash where class = '$batch' order by id asc");
                        
                           while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($all_query)) {
                                 $i++;
                        ?>
                      <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $data['id']; ?> <input type="hidden" name="stat_id[]" value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>"> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $data['name']; ?><input type="hidden" name="stat_name[]" value="<?php echo $data['name']; ?>"></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data['fname']; ?> <input type="hidden" name="stat_fname[]" value="<?php echo $data['fname']; ?>"> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $data['class']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                          <input type="number" name="st_status[<?php echo $number; ?>]" style="width:70px" id="totalDaysX<?php echo $number; ?>"> <!-- Update ID pattern -->
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <?php
                        $number++;
                               }
                           }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <center><br>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-md-offset-10" value="Save!" name="save" />
                  </center>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You talk about a database query, and how you want to display the results in a table - but you have not shown us code for any of those two parts, so how could we possibly tell what might be going wrong in how these three parts play together, when you show us only one of them?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="datatables-new/datatables.min.css">
<script src="datatables-new/datatables.min.js"></script>
<title>Total Days in a Month</title> 
</head>
<body>

  <form>
    <div>
        <label for="month">Select a month:</label>
        <input type="month" id="inputmonth">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="totalDays">Total days in selected month:</label>
        <input type="text" id="calculatedays" readonly>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#inputmonth').on('change', function() {
        var selectedMonth = $(this).val();
        var date = new Date(selectedMonth);
        var totalDays = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
        $('#calculatedays').val(totalDays);
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry, this code doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i have edited my code try it.